# Is it correct to say on yesterday?

Tags: grammar

Is this a correct statement - "I spoke to his wife on yesterday"

Comment: No. Here 'yesterday' is an adverb not a noun. So, no need for a preposition before it.

Comment: This is OK: "I spoke to his wife on Tuesday".  But also not OK: *"I spoke to his wife on last week"

Answer (score 7):

The expression “ on yesterday” is commonnly used in some parts of the United States and while it is colloquially accepted it is not grammatically correct and shouldn't be used during formal scenarios.

As suggested in the following extract by [Merrian-Webster](http://learnersdictionary.com/qa/On-Tomorrow):

> The phrases "on tomorrow," "on today," and "on yesterday" are commonly heard in the southern region of the United States. ***They are acceptable in casual speech and other informal contexts, but should not be used in formal contexts such as academic writing.***
>
> Grammarians and English teachers will tell you not to use the preposition "on" with the adverbs "tomorrow," "today," and "yesterday" because it is already a part of their meaning. Tomorrow is defined as "on the day after today," today is defined as "on this day," and ***yesterday is defined as "on the day before today.***"
>
> ***Since their meanings include the preposition "on" it is redundant to use it.*** On the other hand, if you are naming a specific day, like Monday or Friday, you can use the preposition "on," but you don't need to. Below are some examples.

Comment: Interesting argument. It implies that the sentence "tomorrow is a new day" is also not grammatically correct because it is equivalent to "on the day after today is a new day." (But +1 for the information on geographic prevalence and the source.)

Answer (score -2):

Yesterday, last night, next week all these do not require prepositions please.